# Any good open source charting for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, charts

Are there any good open source .NET chart components out there that are good for large data plotting and real-time charting? I saw some related topics but they were since 2010 and older, so I'm not sure if they are still valid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Syncfusion provides a Chart library for all .NET platforms. While not open source, the libraries are available under a community license as well (see details below).

[Essential Chart for WPF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/sfchart)

[Essential Chart for Windows Forms](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-forms/chart)

[Essential Chart for ASP.NET](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/chart/loadpoints.aspx)

[Essential Chart for ASP.NET MVC](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/aspnetmvc/chart)

[image: Chart Performance]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: This license is still available in 2020. It's a very powerful product and a bit of a game-changer for hobbyists and small businesses looking to code sophisticated charts and UIs - I'm not aware of anything open-source that's even in the same ballpark.

Answer (score 2):

*So, even though this is quite an old question, it has popped up on recent google searches so I am posting this here so that it may help anyone still searching for something similar!*

A good option is [LightningChart Ultimate](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-ultimate-sdk/)! LightningChart provides an entire suite of hardware-accelerated charting components that can be especially useful if real-time performance matters to your application. With the support of real-time rendering of upwards of **15+ Billion** data points, 2D and 3D chart support, along with a comprehensive API for theming and customization and a very shallow learning curve, LightningChart can help your project deal with any data visualization challenge that crops up!
We also have various licensing options for students and teams of any size.

[image: 3D data visualization with LightningChart]

*I work as a senior dev for LightningChart, so if you have some queries, please don't hesitate to ping me.*

Comment: This looks very nice but it is neither open source nor community licensed and therefore doesn't address the actual question.

Comment: We do have a community license. You can find more information about it here ( https://www.arction.com/community-license/ )

Comment: That appears to cover your Javascript charts while the question was about .NET charting.